# How to implement infinite multidimensional array?

Tags: c++, arrays, size

I want to use the code below and I want to use it for "unknown size of input". For example there is an array `int cac[1000][1000]`. I can use `vector<vector<int> > array;`, then how can i initialize it with `-1` ? Any suggestions?

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory.h>

using namespace std;

int cac[1000][1000];
string res[1000][1000];
vector<string> words;
int M;

int go(int a, int b){
 if(cac[a][b]>= 0) return cac[a][b];
 if(a == b) return 0;

 int csum = -1;
 for(int i=a; i<b; ++i){
  csum += words[i].size() + 1;
 }
 if(csum <= M || a == b-1){
  string sep = "";
    for(int i=a; i<b; ++i){
        res[a][b].append(sep);
        res[a][b].append(words[i]);
        sep = " ";
    }
  return cac[a][b] = (M-csum)*(M-csum);
 }

 int ret = 1000000000;
 int best_sp = -1;
 for(int sp=a+1; sp<b; ++sp){
 int cur = go(a, sp) + go(sp,b);
 if(cur <= ret){
    ret = cur;
    best_sp = sp;
 }
 }
 res[a][b] = res[a][best_sp] + "\n" + res[best_sp][b];
 return cac[a][b] = ret;
 }


int main(int argc, char ** argv){
memset(cac, -1, sizeof(cac));
M = atoi(argv[1]);
string word;
while(cin >> word) words.push_back(word);
go(0, words.size());
cout << res[0][words.size()] << endl;
}
```

Comment: What semantics would you expect `-1` to have?

Comment: I'm confused, can you maybe explain what you're looking to do in a little more depth?

Comment: An infinite array is a linked list. That is what it sounds like you want.

Comment: Also, those arrays MUST be dynamically allocated to avoid a stack overflow.

Comment: @ildjarn If an element of cac[][] equals to "-1", then, it means it is not initialized yet. So, i want to do the same for infinite array.

Comment: @pg1989 I want to do word wrapping for unknown size of input.

Comment: Maybe you want `std::vector<boost::optional<std::vector<int>>>`? See [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/). But wouldn't a nested `vector` that's empty serve equally well?

Comment: @ildjarn how can i understand if vector cac[i][j] initilalized or not?

Comment: `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>` That will work better for you I think.

Comment: @vk7x : `if (cac[i].empty()) { /*not initialized*/ }`...

Comment: @ildjarn but cac[i][j].empty() doesn't work?

Comment: @vk7x : `cac[i][j]` is an `int`, and `int` does not have an `empty()` member function, obviously.

Comment: Use a `std::vector<std::string>`. Each item in the vector can be a text line.  The vector will grow as needed, so will the string.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to use a associative array, where the key is a pair (`rowPosition`, `ColumnPosition`). When you want to set `array[i][j]` you just add or update the value `assoArray[Pair(i,j)]`. You can assume that any element which is not in the associative array has the initial value.

In general infinite multidimensional arrays are used for theoretical purpose.I hope i didn't misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 0):

Using std::vector from the STL is much more straightforward than the following solution, which was pointed out in the comments for this post. I find that this site explains that topic effectively: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-programming/16-2-stl-containers-overview/

An array of infinite size is not actually possible. However, you can achieve basically that effect using dynamic allocation. Here's some sample code:

```
int counter = 0;
int* myArray = new int[1000];
```

Fill the array with data, incrementing counter each time you add a value. When counter reaches 1000, do the following:

```
int* largerArray = new int[2000];
for( int i = 0; i < 1000; i++ )
{
    largerArray[i] = myArray[i];
}
delete[] myArray;
myArray = largerArray;
```

With this method, you create the closest thing possible to an infinitely sized array, and I don't believe performance will be an issue with the copy piece

Comment: I don't believe that type of mistake is deserving of a downvote for my post. You are correct though, good suggestion

Comment: My downvote was incentive for you to change your post. And it will be withdrawn once you have done so.

Comment: I didn't realize that was possible. That's pretty funny, thanks for the tip  XD .