# Huge vector "hangs" program? (50000 x 50000 cells)

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array, size

I want to have an array, grid[50000][50000], i tried to do with vector but when i run the code, it stops. No error. Just waits.Any suggestions?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

typedef std::vector<int> IntVec;
typedef std::vector<IntVec> IntGrid;
IntGrid grid(50000, IntVec(50000));

int main(){
  grid[0][0]=3;
  cout<<grid[0][0]<<endl;
}
```

Comment: *"I want to have an array, grid[50000][50000],"* - why?  Is this an actual requirement or a perceived requirement based on you proposed implementation?  That's way too much memory to grab up, there may be a better approach, but you need to tell us the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: @EdS. Could you look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437622/how-to-implement-infinite-multidimensional-array/10438688#10438688 i want to use that code for at least 50k input. cac[50k][50k].

Comment: @vk7x: Wanting things won't make them happen. You should look up sparse matrices and such.

Comment: Suggestions from the linked question tend to point you towards something like `std::map<int, std::vector<int>>` or any other form of sparse storage scheme. Holding this much memory at once is almost impossible (unless you own a high end machine and you are optimistic about your OS's resource management).

Comment: @AlexandreC. Okay. I understand. Now, how can i deal with that? Implementing word wrapping algorithm with 50k words?

Comment: @vk7x: I don't know precisely about word wrapping algorithms, so I cannot help here. Would you mind asking another question, describing what you *want to do* precisely (ie. word wrapping, if possible with a layman's description of the algorithm you intend to use), and the input size requirements you have ? You'll likely get more useful answers than the ones here, since you will be asking about your actual problem, which may have many solutions you did not think about.

Comment: @vk7x: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586/best-word-wrap-algorithm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a very rough calculation,

50,000 rows × 50,000 columns × 4 bytes/integer = `10,000,000,000 bytes`.

Unless your computer has more than 10 GB of RAM, you've run out of memory.

Can you rewrite your program to work with smaller chunks of data, or to use a file to store the parts of the array that don't require immediate access?

Comment: Could you look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437622/how-to-implement-infinite-multidimensional-array/10438688#10438688 i want to use that code for at least 50k input. cac[50k][50k].

Comment: Why don't you tell us what you're trying to accomplish?  Maybe we can come up with a more efficient solution.

Comment: Actually, any normal x86-64 Linux setup should be able to allocate that much memory, using swap space. But that is very slow compared to RAM.

Comment: It's actually probably at least twice that when you factor in the storage for the vector iterators ...

Comment: @AJG85: no, the space overhead of `std::vector` is constant so for a nested one that overhead is _O_ (_n_), which is completely neglectable vs the _O_ (_n_ ²) data amount when n is as large as 50000.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Do nested vectors not maintain their own begin and end pointers etc? I suppose it would only add a few hundred MB which is relatively small in comparison even if that was the case.

Comment: @AJG85 `vector` probably has three words: pointer, size, and capacity. On a 64-bit implementation that's 24 bytes/vector. 50K * 24 is about 1MB overhead for the struct vector. Maybe that much again for the malloc overhead, so we've got a few MB, not hundreds.